# How to add/fill character with leading zeros (hms with delimiter)?

Tags: r, string

I have a set of time values

```
c("23:18:00", "15:02:00", "16:20:00", "16:40:00", "22:06:00", 
"18:03:00", "22:00:00", "19:33:00", "22:16:00", "0:33:00", "17:30:00", 
"22:25:00", "18:54:00", "4:41:00", "17:40:00", "1:00:00", "1:01:00", 
"18:23:00", "20:08:00", "1:50:00")
```

I would like to add leading zeros in two pairs for hour, minute, and second in between the `:` so as to make the string value `"1:50:00"` into `"01:50:00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, we can also left-pad strings with `0` to the width of 8 characters:

```r
stringr::str_pad(t, width = 8, pad = "0")
#>  [1] "23:18:00" "15:02:00" "16:20:00" "16:40:00" "22:06:00" "18:03:00"
#>  [7] "22:00:00" "19:33:00" "22:16:00" "00:33:00" "17:30:00" "22:25:00"
#> [13] "18:54:00" "04:41:00" "17:40:00" "01:00:00" "01:01:00" "18:23:00"
#> [19] "20:08:00" "01:50:00"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
v = c("23:18:00", "15:02:00", "16:20:00", "16:40:00", "22:06:00", 
  "18:03:00", "22:00:00", "19:33:00", "22:16:00", "0:33:00", "17:30:00", 
  "22:25:00", "18:54:00", "4:41:00", "17:40:00", "1:00:00", "1:01:00", 
  "18:23:00", "20:08:00", "1:50:00")

v %>% str_replace('(^\\d:)', '0\\1')

# [1] "23:18:00" "15:02:00" "16:20:00" "16:40:00" "22:06:00" "18:03:00" "22:00:00" "19:33:00" "22:16:00"
# [10] "00:33:00" "17:30:00" "22:25:00" "18:54:00" "04:41:00" "17:40:00" "01:00:00" "01:01:00" "18:23:00"
# [19] "20:08:00" "01:50:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `readr`s `parse_time`, using `as.character` to match the desired output

```
library(readr)

as.character(parse_time(v))
 [1] "23:18:00" "15:02:00" "16:20:00" "16:40:00" "22:06:00" "18:03:00"
 [7] "22:00:00" "19:33:00" "22:16:00" "00:33:00" "17:30:00" "22:25:00"
[13] "18:54:00" "04:41:00" "17:40:00" "01:00:00" "01:01:00" "18:23:00"
[19] "20:08:00" "01:50:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using `ITime` in the `data.table` library

```
library(data.table)
times <- c("23:18:00", "15:02:00", "16:20:00", "16:40:00", "22:06:00", 
       "18:03:00", "22:00:00", "19:33:00", "22:16:00", "0:33:00", "17:30:00", 
       "22:25:00", "18:54:00", "4:41:00", "17:40:00", "1:00:00", "1:01:00", 
       "18:23:00", "20:08:00", "1:50:00")
times <- times |> as.ITime(format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

In **base R** using `sub` with a regex,

```
sub('(^\\d)(?=:)', '0\\1', tm, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "04:41:00" "17:40:00" "01:00:00"
```

or `gsub` (single-digit minutes/seconds are rather unlikely, though)

```
gsub('(\\b\\d(?=:)|(?<=:)\\d\\b)', '0\\1', c("4:41:00", "17:0:00", "1:0:0"), perl=TRUE)
# [1] "04:41:00" "17:00:00" "01:00:00"
```

Alternatively `stri_pad` from the `stringi` package (defaults to left pad)

```
stringi::stri_pad(tm, 8, 0)
# [1] "04:41:00" "17:40:00" "01:00:00"
```

---

*Data:*

```
tm <- c("4:41:00", "17:40:00", "1:00:00")
```